# How To Ensure All Objects on Same Axis?

Tags: unity, .fbx, quaternion

I'm making something in Blender and porting it into Unity as an FBX. The armature is a series of connected bones for each segment/ball. The first segment will move side to side when I rotate on the Y axis (in Unity). The second segment will instead twist if rotated on the Y axis and requires me to use the Z axis to move side to side instead. What gives? It's the same bone structure, shouldn't they be on the same axes? I tried changing all the objects to "Quaternion (WXYZ)" instead of "XYZ Euler" but that doesn't seem to solve this particular problem. Ideas?? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It all depends on how the bones are oriented in their rest pose. Maybe with a screenshot that shows your situation and the bones' axes, we can me of more help.

Comment: They're all oriented in a straight line on the Y axis (Blender's Y axis).

Comment: That doesn't describe the full orientation of the bones. They can be rolled around any angle and still be aligned with the world Y-axis.

Comment: Does the additional image help? I'm not sure how to capture what you're after.